# WAMP Server not accessible locally instead redirects online

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp

a friend of mine is having issues with her WAMP,
she is using WAMP 3.1 each time she fires up localhost 
on her browser it takes her online, but she wants to fireup
localhost to access files on her local computer. The WAMP
server turns green and the WAMP is using Port 80 when
I checked on the http.conf file. Please I will need help
in solve this issue, thanks in anticipation.

Comment: check your hosts file - also, show vhosts file.. as it stands this q is too broad

Comment: Also if you are using Chrome, its gets a bit bitter and twisted (All for your own protection of course) about using `localhost`, so try Firefox or even Edge to see if they do it also

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly my host file is located in this path c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and the localhost ip is written this way 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1 localhost

Comment: Wopps, missed the `system32` folder sorry :)

Comment: Are you using Chrome

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried Firefox and still not working

Comment: I think the problem is from the system, but I can't figure it out the error message I get when I restart the system restarts or launch is **Can not find script file**

Comment: So what Exactly do you enter into address bar